# Magento 2 custom configuration value not saving?

Tags: magento2

I am new to Magento 2.

I tried to create custom admin configuration section with **simple text**, **drop-down** and **color picker** fields. When I tried to save the values, the configuration is not saved in database.

I referred [this link](https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/system-configuration/)

Comment: clear all caches and then try

Comment: which magento2 version are you using?

Comment: i install Magento 2.0.7